# what happens when address send by address register is lost before reaching the destiantion

Tags: cpu-architecture

What happens when address send by address register is lost before reaching the destination?

A teacher asked this question and I couldn't find the answer anywhere. 
Please help.

Comment: What is lost? the content of the register? the message?

Comment: There's no such thing as `lost`, but there are some cases where an operation has to be restarted. Please describe the exact scenario